# App Script custom function works but returns #NUM after some time

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Two of my custom functions have a very strange behaviour in one of my google sheets.
When I enter them, everything works fine, but after some time they return #NUM.

This is one of them, it basically takes the value of a named field (in this case 'costWaterM3') and multiplies it by the average usage parameter.

```
/**
 * Calculates the total water cost
 *
 * @param {number} m3 water usage per year (in m3) 
 * @return total cost
 * @customfunction
 */
function WaterCost(avgUsage) {
  var costWaterM3 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('costWaterM3').getValue();
  return avgUsage * costWaterM3;
}
```

This is how I call the function. `waterUsageCoffeeShop` is a predefined value from a settings table.
(Same table as `costWaterM3` from the function above)

[image: this is how I call the function]

At first it works fine, but when I come back to the sheet, it's kaput.

[image: the resulting error]

I have even tried copying the faulty cell to another one, and it works like a charm. Until that one breaks too. There is another function in the same script file, and this works like a charm all the time.

Veeeeery strange. What am I missing here?

Comment: Can you please share a sample spreadsheet with your desired output?

Comment: The function generally works fine, it just stops working at some point.

Comment: It will be helpful if you can share so I can replicate your concern.

Comment: I can't share the original one with you, but I created a test sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ISaqQNotyNvXlgnU3-J3Gp1o7HZX53htFLTqmxvMFoY/edit?usp=sharing

I *think* I'm one step further. The named range that is used in the function contains another really simple function to change the local currency to eur.:

```function Lei2Eur(lei) {

  var exchangeRate = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('Lei2EurRate').getValue();

  return  lei / exchangeRate;

}```

If I replace that function with the numeric value, everything seems to work fine...

Answer (score 0):

This usually means that the result of `avgUsage * costWaterM3` is `NaN`. It is `NaN`, because at least one of the variables `avgUsage` or `costWaterM3` is not getting a number.

You can try logging them both and returning the final result:

```
console.log({avgUsage, costWaterM3})
const result = avgUsage * costWaterM3;
console.log({result})
return result;
```

The logs can then be examined to find the cause. My guess is either one of those named ranges is not returning a number.

Comment: This is from the log `WaterCost: 200.0 * #ERROR! = NaN` Meaning the passed argument works fine, but the named Range doesn't work. I checked, the range exists but returns the string `#ERROR!`. 

But why only after the first execution? First run always works, then later it breaks

Comment: I think I'm one step further, the cell `costWaterM3` contains another custom function that changes the local currency to eur. If I replace that function with the numeric value, everything seems to be stable. You can try it out here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ISaqQNotyNvXlgnU3-J3Gp1o7HZX53htFLTqmxvMFoY/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @TimSchoch So, this is a chained custom function? The first one somehow fails and the error is propogated to the second one... Your best bet is to combine both  the functions into one thereby skipping the sheet for the intermediary step. Another option is to explicitly check whether both the variables are numbers. If not, sleep for a while and check again.

Comment: correct, the chained custom function returns an error. I'll try the sleep function and test if it solves the issue, and if so, how much slower the whole thing feels